# Jaspersoft 6.3: Create hyperlinks for chart data series

Tags: highcharts, hyperlink, jasper-reports, series

I have read answers to several similar questions.
(Answers are for versions of jaspersoft older than 6.3 do not apply - i believe those methods have been deprecated.)

I think the following three posts relate to my question, but I do not know **how to implement the solution in JasperSoft Studio**.

- [Highcharts - URL's for series data to open clickable link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37988348/highcharts-urls-for-series-data-to-open-clickable-link?rq=1)
- [Highcharts - Provide URL's for series data to open clickable link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16176390/highcharts-provide-urls-for-series-data-to-open-clickable-link?rq=1)
- [making series in Highcharts clickable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21980828/making-series-in-highcharts-clickable?rq=1)

Problem

1. **I have a line chart report that I created server-side** based off of an Ad Hoc View. (The reason I created it server-side instead of in Studio is because I wanted the dynamic sizing and some other attractive formatting that is default in server-side-generated content and very difficult to replicate when creating in studio).
2. As in the 3 posts I referenced above, **I want each series in the chart to link to another report**.
3. This is my **JRXML for the highchart**

:

```
   <jrhc:chart xmlns:jrhc="http://jaspersoft.com/highcharts" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jaspersoft.com/highcharts http://jaspersoft.com/schema/highcharts.xsd" type="Line">
        <jrhc:chartSetting name="_jrs_adhoc">
            <jrhc:chartProperty name="_JRS_ADHOC_CHART_STATE"> 
                <jrhc:propertyExpression><![CDATA[$P{_JRS_ADHOC_CHART_STATE}]]>
                </jrhc:propertyExpression>
            </jrhc:chartProperty
            <jrhc:chartProperty name="_JRS_ADHOC_QUERY_DATA">
                <jrhc:propertyExpression><![CDATA[$P{_JRS_ADHOC_QUERY_DATA}]]>
                </jrhc:propertyExpression>
            </jrhc:chartProperty>
        </jrhc:chartSetting>
    </jrhc:chart>
```

4. When i add the following **code for the series click event**, i get this error:

(right now i'm just trying to get the series hyperlinking to work; after that I can implement the URL for passing values and opening the other report)

```
    <jrhc:chartProperty name="plotOptions.series.events.click">
        <jrhc:propertyExpression><![CDATA[function() { window.open('http://www.google.com');}]]></jrhc:propertyExpression>
    </jrhc:chartProperty>
```

**Error** (this is not the complete error; hoping this is a sufficient amount of the error to explain the problem):

> Errors were encountered when compiling report expressions class file:
>
> 1. Syntax error, insert "AssignmentOperator Expression" to complete Assignment value = function() {
>      window.open('http://www.google.com');}; //$JR_EXPR_ID=19$ <--->
> 2. Syntax error, insert ";" to complete Statement value = function() { window.open('http://www.google.com');}; //$JR_EXPR_ID=19$ <--->
> 3. Syntax error, insert "}" to complete Block value = function() { window.open('http://www.google.com');}; //$JR_EXPR_ID=19$ <--->
> 4. Syntax error, insert "}" to complete SwitchBlock value = function() { window.open('http://www.google.com');}; //$JR_EXPR_ID=19$
>      <--->
> 5. Syntax error, insert "}" to complete MethodBody value = function() { window.open('http://www.google.com');}; //$JR_EXPR_ID=19$ <--->
> 6. Return type for the method is missing value = function() { window.open('http://www.google.com');}; //$JR_EXPR_ID=19$ <------->
> 7. Duplicate method function() in type Report32Oil32Production32Line32Chart32_1508349588993_985918 value =
>      function() { window.open('http://www.google.com');}; //$JR_EXPR_ID=19$
>      <-------->
> 8. Invalid character constant value = function() { window.open('http://www.google.com');}; //$JR_EXPR_ID=19$ <>

5. **Is it possible** to add this series-hyperlinking functionality to a server-side generated report? If yes, where do i add the javascript and **what is the proper syntax**?

Comment: Please check this. It might help you https://community.jaspersoft.com/jaspersoft-studio/issues/3521.

Comment: The JavaScript function/code needs to be passed as a String.  E.g. (mind the quotes):
<jrhc:propertyExpression><![CDATA["function() { window.open('http://www.google.com');}"]]></jrhc:propertyExpression>

Comment: Thank you  - formatting the expression as a string got rid of the error. The hyperlink functionality is still not working, but knowing how to pass java functions is really useful.

Comment: @FahadAnjum the link to the jaspersoft community you provided looks like pertained to a bug issue with jaspersoft 5.5. I am using version 6.3. Do i still need to add this line to \WEB-INF\classes\jasperreports.properties and restart the server: com.jaspersoft.jasperreports.highcharts.function.properties.allowed=true. Per this post (https://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/functions-can-be-used-format-html5-datalabels-and-tooltips)

Comment: Yes, you still need to set that property (and restart).  Can't tell whether plotOptions.series.events.click would actually work though, but it's worth trying.